# Slow indexing and/or hashing in nearly low memory in OSX

Tags: macos, ssd, memory, bug, indexing

I have observed slow indexing and/or hashing in OSX which are expressed in the SSD disc which is nearly full (about 5% free space). 
This bug has been reported to me to exist in earlier OSXs too so not only OSX Yosemite. 
The system is Macbook Air 2013-mid. 
This bug may be related to the similar bug with long filenames which indexing and/or hashing takes much time in the same system and settings, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175294/15504) discussion.

I notice slow indexing and/or hashing in installing basic commands through homebrew and just doing basic search in Finder with long filenames:

- Slow rehashing (reported to me no indexing necessary) in nearly low SSD-memory system of Macbook air 2013-mid; I have reproduced it in OSX Yosemite 10.10.2
  See this post [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179410/15504) where patrix deleted my notice about slow indexing.
- Slow indexing and/or hashing also occurs in searching long filenames, discussion [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/175294/15504).

To reproduce it, you need

- nearly low SSD memory

This indexing problem may be caused by handling of SSD memories and temporary memory.

**How have you resolved the challenge of memory management in OSX?**
I do not know the level of memory when the problems starts to occur.

Comment: The way `bash` finds external commands doesn't require any indexing, so slow indexing doesn't explain the problems you've experienced in the linked question. I'm nevertheless curious about answers to the problem in general.

Comment: @patrix Excellent notice! Yes, me too. I would like to understand this issue better and waiting a public notice from Apple because this is irritating problem. Now, I minimize the challenge by having the Trascends OSX 128GB SSD card in my memory slot and moving unnecessary stuff to there. This way providing space for temporary memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is a history note for a bug report to Apple, made [here](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html). 
As discussed earlier with admins, this is ok, since this is one attempt for solution. 
Apple does not keep public those reports and does not send any documentation to users so we must keep them public, since they do not do it.

[image]